# Pagination inside foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I try create pagination inside loop foreach for show results , the problem no works for me , i create this little script :

```
foreach ($array as $pag_id=>$array_2)
{


$results_by_page="2";

if ($_REQUEST['page']=="")
{
$pag_ini=0;
$pag_end="$results_by_page";
}

if ($_REQUEST['page']=="0")
{
$pag_ini=0;
$pag_end="$results_by_page";
}


if ($_REQUEST['page']=="1")
{
$pag_ini="".$results_by_page."";
$pag_end="".($results_by_page+$pag_ini)."";
}

if ($_REQUEST['page']>"1")
{

$pag_end="".($_REQUEST['page']*$results_by_page)."";
$pag_ini="".($pag_end-$results_by_page)."";

}


if ($pag_id==$pag_ini && $pag_id<=$pag_end)
{
break;
}



}
```

I don´t know if it´s possible create paginaton using this loop buy i need use it

With loop **for** no give me problem do this , but in this case i need use **foreach**

Also if exists other method for pagination inside this kind of loop you can put here

Thank´s for community the help

Answer (score 0):

If you had it working before with a `for` loop, why not do this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $pag_id=>$array_2)
{
    // Your existing code
    //Do whatever you were doing with $i before
    $i++;
}
```

You then can do what you were doing in the `for` loop while keeping the benefits of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: sorry but don´t understad you tell me

Comment: You said you had it working with a `for` loop but you needed to use a `foreach` instead. If you add `$i = 0;` before the `foreach` loop and add `$i++;` inside the `foreach` loop at the end you get a `foreach` loop with the included functionality of the `for` loop. You then just use `$i` where ever you were using it when you had it working with the `for` loop.

Comment: Sorry i try but no works with the conditions i think there is the problem , regards